# Python Web Scraping : cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

New to python and trying to scrape my first website by googling. I think I have hit a deadend with unusual error.

```python
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="http://property.sulekha.com/apartments-flats-in-pimpri-chinchwad-general-pune-for-sale"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"title"})

for item in g_data:
        Desp = item.contents[1].text
        Location = item.contents[5].text
        Address = item.contents[3].text
        #Print Desp,Location,Address
        #Problem is over here,The result set that i am getting is quite scatter. I want to put it into
        #pandas object and then output to excel.
        output_df = pd.concat([Desp,Location,Address])
```

What I am trying to do ?
whatever dataset I am getting I want to export it to Excel.

Comment: What is Desp? Location and Address are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For writing to excel just do `df.to_excel('file_name', index=None)`

Check this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="http://property.sulekha.com/apartments-flats-in-pimpri-chinchwad-general-pune-for-sale"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Desp', 'Location', 'Address'])
g_data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"title"})
for item in g_data:
    Desp = ' '.join(item.contents[1].text.split())
    loc = ' '.join(item.contents[5].text.split()).split(',')
    Location = loc[0][9:]
    Address = loc[1]
    df = df.append({'Desp':Desp, 'Location':Location, 'Address': Address}, ignore_index=True)

df.head()
```

Output:

[image]